# Jenkins HTML Publisher Plugin 1.3 gives 404 error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using the CoverageConverter.exe (Code coverage tool for .net apps) plugin for generating code coverage xml file and ReportGenerator.exe (1.9.1.0) to generate html reports for code coverage.
Configured HTML Publisher plugin (1.3) to display html reports for code coverage.
Jenkins version - 1.569

Html files are archived to the below location by Jenkins after the build
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Job_name\htmlreports\HTML_Report\

HTML publisher creates the link with 
/job/job_name/HTML_Report/index.html

HTML Publisher plugin creates the link on the dashboard but after clicking the link unable to see the report and it's shows the below error:
Status Code: 404

Exception:
Stacktrace:
(none)

Answer (score 3):

Issue has been resolved. Reports was in htm format.

Comment: to be more precious, in input for the jenkin plugin the index.htm should be given rather index.html. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Copy the HTML file to your workspace after its generated.

```
Copy /y C:\Archive\HtmlCoverage.html %WORKSPACE%
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML file is already present in %WORKSPACE%. From this folder HTML publisher is archiving to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Job_name\htmlreports\HTML_Report\